# How to promote the idea of 2nd law of thermodynamic to microscopic scale

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, photons, entropy

The deduction of the 2nd law of thermodynamics is based on the concept of heat energy and the working material of ideal gases, but how could this law be promoted to other areas on the microscopic scale which includes other formats of energy like photons? If the 2nd law is universal law on any scale of time and space, is it possible to define the entropy of a single particle?

Answer (score 2):

The quantum mechanical evolution of a single particle (pure state) is described by the Schrodinger equation. Since this evolution is unitary and reversible, the entropy of a single quantum particle is zero.

It [can be shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) that since $$S = -\text{Tr}(\rho \ln \rho)$$ then for a pure quantum state $S=0$.

Comment: What the differential form of the 2nd law of thermodynamics would be if there is an interaction between two single particles? I guess there should be entropy production when there is an interaction.

Comment: If the state is a mixed state, then the entropy would not be zero. But your question is for a single particle pure state. Cheers.